# How to call Kotlin coroutine in composable function callbacks?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose

I want to call a suspend-function inside of a callback of composable-function.

```kotlin
suspend fun getLocation(): Location? { /* ... */ }

@Composable
fun F() {

    val (location, setLocation) = remember { mutableStateOf<Location?>(null) }

    val getLocationOnClick: () -> Unit = {
        /* setLocation __MAGIC__ getLocation */
    }

    Button(onClick = getLocationOnClick) {
        Text("detectLocation")
    }

}
```

If I would have used Rx then I could just `subscribe`.

I could do `invokeOnCompletion` and then `getCompleted`, but that API is experimental.

I can't use `launchInComposition` in `getLocationOnClick` because `launchInComposition` is `@Composable` and `getLocationOnClick` can not be `@Composable`.

What would be the best way to get result of a suspending function inside a regular function, inside `@Composable` function?

Comment: You can call a function of a ViewModel which launches a suspend function on the viewmodelScope

Comment: Otherwise, if you have a reference to an AppCompatActivity you could use its lifecycle scope

Comment: You mean like `SomeScope.async { setLocation(getLocation()) }`? Thank you, that actually works, I did not expect it to be that simple. Would you please kindly comment that as an answer (so that I could mark this question as resolved).

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Create a coroutines scope, tied to the lifecycle of your composable, and use that scope to call your suspending function

```
suspend fun getLocation(): Location? { /* ... */ }

@Composable
fun F() {
    // Returns a scope that's cancelled when F is removed from composition
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val (location, setLocation) = remember { mutableStateOf<Location?>(null) }

    val getLocationOnClick: () -> Unit = {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val location = getLocation()
        }
    }

    Button(onClick = getLocationOnClick) {
        Text("detectLocation")
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/kotlin#coroutines 
...from the docs

Answer (score 11):

This works for me:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TheComposable() {

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val (loadResult, setLoadResult) = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

    IconButton(
        onClick = {
            someState.startProgress("Draft Loading...")
            coroutineScope.launch {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    try {
                        loadResult = DataAPI.getData() // <-- non-suspend blocking method
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        // handle exception
                    } finally {
                        someState.endProgress()
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.TwoTone.Call, contentDescription = "Load")
    }
```

I also tried out the following helper function, to force dev-colleagues to handle Exceptions and to finally cleanup state (also to make the same code (maybe!?) a bit shorter and (maybe!?) a bit more readable):

```kotlin
fun launchHelper(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
                 catchBlock: (Exception) -> Unit,
                 finallyBlock: () -> Unit,
                 context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
                 start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
                 block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Job {
    return coroutineScope.launch(context, start) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                block()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                catchBlock(e)
            } finally {
                finallyBlock()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's how to use that helper method:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TheComposable() {

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val (loadResult, setLoadResult) = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

    IconButton(
        onClick = {
            someState.startProgress("Draft Loading...")
            launchHelper(coroutineScope,
                catchBlock = { e -> myExceptionHandling(e) },
                finallyBlock = { someState.endProgress() }
            ) {
                loadResult = DataAPI.getData() // <-- non-suspend blocking method
            }

        }
    ) {
        Icon(Icons.TwoTone.Call, contentDescription = "Load")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the viewModelScope of a ViewModel or any other coroutine scope.

Example of Deleting Action for an Item from LazyColumnFor which requires a suspend call handled by a ViewModel.

```kotlin
     class ItemsViewModel : ViewModel() {

        private val _itemList = MutableLiveData<List<Any>>()
        val itemList: LiveData<List<Any>>
            get() = _itemList

        fun deleteItem(item: Any) {
            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                TODO("Fill Coroutine Scope with your suspend call")       
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Example() {
        val itemsVM: ItemsViewModel = viewModel()
        val list: State<List<Any>?> = itemsVM.itemList.observeAsState()
        list.value.let { it: List<Any>? ->
            if (it != null) {
                LazyColumnFor(items = it) { item: Any ->
                    ListItem(
                        item = item,
                        onDeleteSelf = {
                            itemsVM.deleteItem(item)
                        }
                    )
                }
            } // else EmptyDialog()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun ListItem(item: Any, onDeleteSelf: () -> Unit) {
        Row {
            Text(item.toString())
            IconButton(
                onClick = onDeleteSelf,
                icon = { Icons.Filled.Delete }
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: took a sneak peak at the [viewModelScope extension source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel.kt). Could it be used without ViewModel just with `val scope = remember { CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate) }` and then `onActive { onDispose { scope.cancel() } }`?

Comment: Not great, you don't really know when the operation ends. Just use rememberCoroutinesScope() and turn deleteItem() into a suspending function

Comment: I agree with @heyheyhey , we don't know when the composable will be called, it maybe recalled any number of times so its better to use `rememberCoroutineScope` over `viewModelScope`