# How can I call try/catch in a Composable Button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, try-catch, sqliteexception

I need to catch a SQLiteException in a Composable Button click event.  I am executing a Room function to Insert a record. It has a Unique constraint field/index.

I found the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116377/how-to-call-kotlin-coroutine-in-composable-function-callbacks).

And found Stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116377/how-to-call-kotlin-coroutine-in-composable-function-callbacks)

I tried the accepted option and the third option, but did not work.

Here is my code:

ADO ///////

```
interface houseDAO {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT )
@Throws(SQLiteException::class)
suspend fun addHouse(houseEntity: HouseEntity)

//More DAO functions

}
```

Repository ////////

```
class InventoryRepository (val inventoryDB: InventoryDB){

suspend fun addhouseToRoom(houseEntity: HouseEntity){
    inventoryDB.houseDao().addHouse(houseEntity)
}

 //More functions
}
```

Viewmodel //////////

```
class InventoryViewModel(val repository: InventoryRepository): ViewModel() {

fun addhouse(house: HouseEntity) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.addhouseToRoom(house)
    }
}

//More functions
}
```

Composable function ///////////

```
//More functions

Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(top = 22.dp, start = 6.dp, end = 6.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

            val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

            //Commented line because the addfloor function does not returns any value  
            //val (loadResult, setLoadResult) = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

            Button(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                            try {
                                viewModel.addfloor(
                                    FloorEntity(
                                        0,
                                        houseId!!.toLong(),
                                        infloor,
                                        "$location.$infloor"
                                    )
                                )
                                mToast("Floor Added", mContext)
                            } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
                                msgbox(
                                    mContext,
                                    e.message.toString(),
                                    "Floor Could not be Added"
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Blue)

            ) {
                Text(text = "Add Floor in to House")
            }
        }

//More functions
```

The error is catched in another place on the application where I have a catch all errors segment.

Comment: If that's not catching the error (and it's getting caught elsewhere), then the issue is that you're not catching the right type.  Could you post the stack trace to verify?

Comment: why would you want to have this on the composable side ? you have so many other places to deal with it

Comment: It was catchig the SqliteException caused by the Unique constraint. I run in debug mode and could see the error.

Comment: I was trying to do the error catch in the Compose function to handle the messages in the graphic side of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I tried directly in the Viewmodel and it work.

DAO and Repository code is the same

Viewmodel ////////

```
fun addroom(mContext: Context, room: RoomEntity) {
   viewModelScope.launch {
       try {
           repository.addroomToRoom(room)
           msgbox(mContext, "", "Room Added")
       } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
           msgbox(mContext, e.message.toString(), "Room Could not be Added")
       }
   }
}
```

Composable Function ////////

```
Button(
                onClick = {
                        viewModel.addroom(mContext,
                            RoomEntity(
                                0,
                                floorId!!.toLong(),
                                inroomname,
                                inroomtype.value,
                                "$location.$inroomname"
                            )
                        )
                        //mToast("Room Added", mContext)
                },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Blue)

            ) {
                Text(text = "Add Romm into Floor")
            }
```

I removed the Toast message for simplicity and added the success message as part of  the try code. I added the Context from the Compose function.